# 504 Gateway Timed Out on Laravel Forge with PHP-FPM

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-forge

I've had a `504 Gateway Timed Out` error for two days on my website hosted on Laravel Forge.

After a lot of investigation and testing, I've deduced that only certain models are causing the problem (such as users or media).
Some things work, such as `User::find(1)` for example, but `User::all()` (40 entries in the database) doesn't work.

An example of the nginx logs:

```
2024/01/18 15:31:37 [error] 23247#23247: *1216 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: ***.***.***.***, server: *****.com, request: "GET /bibliotheque/images HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock", host: "****.com"
```

I've tried everything, changing things in the PHP-FPM pool configuration, nginx...

I've run out of ideas...

I tried to

- Restart the server
- Change max timeout in PHP-FPM
- Add prameters in nginx

And nothing works